# NSMutableArray sorted

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a question about sorting NSMutableArray. For example I have an NSMutableArray elements of which it NSArray.

```
(
    (
    "00:07",
    name1,
),
    (
    "03:07",
    name1,
),
(
    "01:07",
    name2,
),
)
```

I need to sort the NSMutableArray by the first element of NSArray. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to do custom sorting:

```
[myArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSArray *a, NSArray *b) {
  if (/* check if a should be after b */) {
    return NSOrderedAscending;
  } else if (/* check if a should be before b */) {
    return NSOrderedDescending;
  }

  // they have the same sorting weight, so position doesn't matter
  return NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

But in your case you can make it easier, by offloading most of the work to NSString:

```
[myArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSArray *a, NSArray *b) {
  return [[a objectAtIndex:0] compare:[b objectAtIndex:0]];
}];
```